# React route not working with custom navbar

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navbar, react-router-dom

I am using a custom navbar library that I found on NPM to render my navbar but the `navlinks` in the custom navbar are not working. When I click on the links, the route is updated in the address bar but the component is not being rendered. Although when using a simple list, I am able to render all the routes.

[CodeSandbox Example to Replicate](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-http-sswgt?file=/src/App.js)

```
function App() {

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        /* This custom navbar is not working for routing */
        <Navbar></Navbar>

        /* This list is working fine for routing */
        {/* <ul>
            <li>
                <NavLink to='/'>Home</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
                <NavLink to='/about'>About</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
                <NavLink to='/contact'>Contact</NavLink>
            </li>
        </ul> */}

        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route path='/about' component={About} />
            <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
        </Switch>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

This is the custom navbar component that I am using: [Custom Navbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-animate-navbar)

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox link with the same problem

Comment: Do you have a "Router" component around this?

Comment: @Syder yes, i have wrapped the App component with BrowserRouter in index.js

Comment: @GayatriDipali I have added codesandbox example to replicate now : https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-http-sswgt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I guess it's the problem with package, link to the open github issue : https://github.com/Nazeh-Taha/react-responsive-animate-navbar/issues/4, maybe you can find help there

Comment: i think i found the problem but not sure how to test and solve it. if you look at source code here https://github.com/Nazeh-Taha/react-responsive-animate-navbar/blob/master/src/index.js at lines 99-114, when he creates the links it wraps them into a router

Comment: @Syder I also had the same doubt, but could not test it on local as I am short on time these days. I'll try to fix and raise a pull request when I get some free time.

Comment: @PR7 I have fixed the bug, now you can directly pass a component in the menu prop.

Comment: @GayatriDipali did you fix the open issue with the package ? can you update my sandbox link to show the working example. Thanks

Comment: I could but the npm package is not updated yet

Comment: @GayatriDipali Thanks, btw the issue has been fixed in a recent pull request. I am waiting for the NPM package update.

Answer (score 0):

you might forget to wrap your code with
 `<Router> or <BrowserRouter>`.

Try on:

```
import {BrowserRouter, Router} from "react-router-dom";

 <BrowserRouter>
            <React.Fragment>
                ...
            </React.Fragment>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

or

```
<Router>
            <React.Fragment>
                ...
            </React.Fragment>
</Router>
```

Comment: did you try your solution?

Comment: as I said in my description, I have already wrapped the App component with BrowserRouter. So I think this will not work my friend. Please check the code sandbox example that I have added.

Comment: I'm looked at your code @PR7 in the Codesandbox.
Yeah, I have no idea why the router not working. Sorry.

Comment: @AlmazAtun no problem :) There might be some issue with that NPM package as there are some open issue on github for that repository.